# Convert an image to a GeoJSON Polygon (bash/javascript)

Tags: javascript, bash, mapbox, geospatial, geojson

I'm trying to convert an image (e.g. the one below), then get only the grey pixels and return them as a GeoJSON polygon.
[image]

I already have a bash script using ImageMagick that takes the image as entry and convert it into a .txt file

```
convert IMAGE_URL -crop "331x230+82+50" "./tmp/IMAGE_CONVERTED.txt"
```

From here, I run another bash script that loop through all the .txt file and check if the pixel is grey. If so, the pixel goes into an array.

```
LC_ALL="C" awk -f scripts/parse-colors.awk "./tmp/IMAGE_CONVERTED.txt" > "./geojson/IMAGE_CONVERTED.geojson"
```

scripts/parse-colors.awk

```
if (isGrey(r, g, b)) {
  printf "%s{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[%.2f,%.2f]}}", sep, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE
  sep = ","
}
```

After this step, I have a huge GeoJSON, containing points/pixels. That's where I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed to convert these points into a polygon.

Furthermore, with this script, there is a lot of pixels that should be deleted of the array, since they are inside the shape already.

So, how do I do to "clean" these pixels and create a polygon out of it?

The solution can be in javascript if needed. I saw the [Turf](https://turfjs.org/) library but I'm not sure how to use it in my context, and if it's the solution to the problem.

Comment: I think you need a raster to vector processor that will give you only the break points of the boundary. See raster to vector tools such as autotrace or potrace. Alternately, use OpenCV to get the contour and then convert that into a polygon. See cv2.approxPolyDP(). A simpler example is at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you! that's looks interesting. I'll have to dig in to know better how to set it up for my case

I have some line that are going under the shapes that I don't want to be return into the polygon, so not sure if it wouldn't confuse the library or not